# T-SQL query practice/exams/tuning examples

Tags: t-sql

Can the community suggest some T-SQL practice/sample exams, and tips on increasing performance/tuning? This is for preparing interview. Thanks.

Comment: Just say you've used SQL Profiler and that you love poring over execution plans, Stan!  :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [TSQL interview questions you ask..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765857/tsql-interview-questions-you-ask)

Answer (score 3):

T-SQL 'exams' are tough to come by. There are a lot of concepts that you can't really grasp until you've used them (and usually after some very painful hours working on "weird" issues).

Depending on how advanced you're looking to get, if you'd like to really go nuts and see what you're capable of, look at http://beyondrelational.com/tc/ There are challenges that people compete in. If you're looking for more of a try/learn approach, do an older challenge and peek at the answer if you can't quite figure it out.

Actually, looking at the page now I see that they have beginner challenges as well.

Answer (score 1):

An SO search for [interview+questions+sql](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=interview%2Bquestions%2Bsql+site:stackoverflow.com)

To be brutal, you can't learn answers to questions they may ask. Either you know or you don't. It's easily spotted if they hire consultants too (I was interviewed by a famous MS bloke once, had a book or 2 of his on my desk) because they don't yet have in house skills.

Comment: query: "had a bookr or 2 of hos on my desk"?  I have no idea what you are trying to say with this.